# How can I return a string from an ElapsedEvent method

Tags: c#

I have a deserialize function called `DeSerializeXML` that returns a string. I am calling it from a different class I need it to run based on a Timer so I have it being called in the `ElapsedEvent` for the Timer

```
    private void frm_MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new Timer(2000);
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(ElapsedEvent);
        myTimer.Enabled = true;            
    }

    public static void ElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        string x = OtherClass.DeSerializeXML();
    }
```

How can i pull that string value out of the ElapsedEvent so I can assign it to a textbox on the MyForm form?? I apologize if this is a poorly worded question, I will add comments/more code as need be. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Control.Invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

```
public void ElapsedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    string x = OtherClass.DeSerializeXML();
    frm.Invoke((Action)(() => textBox.Text = x);
}
```

**Note**: Remove *static* keyword from the method's signature

Comment: I spoke too soon, i got an exception when i removed the static part. And when i try and use the "Invoke" method it doesnt come up and is not recognized (I am using a windows forms project vs 2012)

Comment: Im trying to use the textbox on a different thread than the one it was created on

Comment: You should use Invoke method.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the returned string as `Text` property of text-box.

```
textBox1.Text = OtherClass.DeSerializeXML();
```

If you get any complications regarding non-UI thread try using `Invoke`. Like this:

```
var txt = OtherClass.DeSerializeXML();
if (InvokeRequired)
{
    //this is the Form
    this.Invoke(new Action<string>(textBox1), new object[] {txt});
    return;
}
textBox1.Text = txt;
```

Comment: the textbox on the form is out of scope so I can only access it from the frm_Load, when I try to type it in for ElapsedEvent nothing comes up

Comment: Where is the textbox? On another form or what?

Comment: its on MyForm, I don't understand why I cant access it from the ElapsedEvent so I figured i had to return the value out of it somehow

Comment: the only part of this thats on another form is the static DeSerialize method that I call